# How to perform traffic filtering and forwarding on a Cisco router?

Tags: routes, cisco

I have a border router R1. I wish to forward all incoming traffic coming from AS 200 via interface f0/0 for destination x.y.z.w to border router R2 with ip address a.b.c.d. However, if the incoming traffic for destination x.y.z.w comes from within the AS (100) I want to forward it to border router R3 with ip address g.h.i.j.
How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I think router can't have traffic filtering rule based on interface, you probably doing something wrong, what's your Use Case?

Comment: @Serith: I want to send all traffic coming from AS p via interface f0/0 for destination x.y.z.w to router with ip address a.b.c.d

Comment: @Serith: I want the packets from my neighbor AS to leave out of a particular border router. How do I do this?

Comment: Have static route in some form to direct traffic to router and have static route on the router (config)#ip route x.y.z.w <subnet mask> a.b.c.d

Comment: @Serith: If the request for x.y.z.w originates from within the AS I want it to exit from a different border router (g.h.i.j). How will I do that?

Comment: If by AS you mean "Access System" then configurate default gateway (which is form of static route as I mentioned in previous comment) on the AS that would point to your border router address and then create static route on your border router that would reroute traffic originated within AS to outside network, I am assuming that you would want to have default route (config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [insert here: next hop router ip addres]

Comment: @Serith: by AS I meant autonomous system.

Comment: The main point remains, you will have to configure routing tables of AS or some other router along the way between AS and border router to send packets with x.y.z.w destination to g.h.i.j border router (you can route by destination not by the source). There is two ways to configure routing table by using static routes or by using routing protocol such as OSP, EIGRP etc. But I am making a lot of assumptions here about your actual network, I really not sure how helpful it is.

Comment: @Serith: I think route-map will help me do what I want.

Comment: I found my answer on [serverfault][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/105605/source-based-routing-on-cisco-3750-switch

Answer (score 2):

I think Policy Based Routing would cover this.  See [this Cisco overview](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6599/products_white_paper09186a00800a4409.shtml#wp14019) of circumstances where PBR is applicable.

To configure, you need a route-map to specify match critera, then enable PBR for that route-map on an interface.  Example taken (and hacked) from [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0/qos/configuration/guide/qcpolicy.html#wp5530).

```
access-list 100 extended permit ip w.w.w.w x.x.x.x
access-list 110 extended permit ip y.y.y.y z.z.z.z

interface ethernet 1
   ip policy route-map AS100

route-map AS100 permit 10
   match ip address 100
   set ip next-hop g.h.i.j

route-map AS200 permit 10
   match ip address 110
   set ip next-hop a.b.c.d
```

You will need access lists to match the traffic, so it's relevant whether you expect to see only traffic source directly from AS200 (presumably a known set of prefixes) or if you will see general internet traffic.

If it's the latter, it might make sense to specify the default route via R2 and use PBR to catch your internal traffic, routing that via R3.

EDIT: Juniper supports source interface routing, I don't believe Cisco IOS12 does.  Question was tagged Cisco so probably not worth changing all your kit just for this but worth noting anyway.